# Is it possible to combine multiple internal modules to one external?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

What I want to achieve is to have such layout:

```
// Shape.ts
module Shape {
    export interface Shape {
        area(): number;        
    }
}

// Rectangle.ts
module Shape {
    export class Rectangle implements Shape {
        constructor(private x:number, private y: number) {}
        area(): number {
            return this.x * this.y;
        }
    }
}

// Square.ts
module Shape {
    export class Square implements Shape  {
        constructor(private x:number) {}
        area(): number {
            return Math.pow(this.x, 2);
        }
    }
}

// geometry.ts
/// <reference path="Shape.ts" />
/// <reference path="Rectangle.ts" />
/// <reference path="Square.ts" />
export = Shape.Rectangle;
export = Shape.Square;
```

where I have most code in regular internal modules. And also, to build a Node.js module, I have an external module, which exports all the stuff, that is intended to be available for Node module users.

But currently, when I invoke `tsc -m commonjs --outFile geometrylib.js geometry.ts`, I get a `geometrylib.js` without any `module.exports` statements, as it supposed to be in CommonJS build.

Is it possible at all with current version of TypeScript?

ps
`tsc --version` gives me `message TS6029: Version 1.6.0-beta`.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to combine multiple internal modules to one external?

instead of

```
export = Shape.Rectangle;
export = Shape.Square;
```

You can do :

```
export = Shape;
```

However *I recommend that you don't mix internal and external modules ... and just as your consumers to respect `npm` and embrace `commonjs`.*

@)--